# Can't fetch data after I change to use fetchResultController instead of FetchRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I use the code below to fetch data originally：

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequeset = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Restaurant"];

        NSError *e = [[NSError alloc] init];
        restaurants = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequeset error:&e];
        if (![managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequeset error:&e]) {
            NSLog(@"%@",e.localizedDescription);
        }
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

My tableView can load the restaurant objects I saved before from database, I can also add new "restaurant" and it works well, but once I replace it with NSFetchedResultsController, it cannot fetch data anymore, the tableView has no content:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Restaurant"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        self.fetchResultController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
        self.fetchResultController.delegate = self;

        NSError *e = [[NSError alloc] init];
        restaurants = [self.fetchResultController fetchedObjects];

        if (![self.fetchResultController performFetch:&e]) {
            NSLog(@"%@",e.localizedDescription);
        }
    }
}
```

So why? How to fix it?

additional remarks:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSUInteger rowIndex = [indexPath row];
    Restaurant *restaurant = restaurants[rowIndex];

    cell.nameLabel.text = restaurant.name;
    cell.typeLabel.text = restaurant.type;
    cell.thumbnailImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:restaurant.image];

    return cell;
```

}

Comment: Have you amended the tableView data source methods to use the FRC instead of the restaurants array?

Comment: thanks for your help. Did you mean that I should replace the restaurants array with [self.fetchResultController fetchedObjects]? I'v tried this but it didn't work.I  added my tableView data source methods at last.@pbasdf

Comment: The current problem is that you set restaurants = [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] *before* the performFetch, so it will be an empty array.  You could just move that line, but there is boilerplate code for using a fetched results controller as the datasource for a table view, which will work far better.

Comment: yeah, you are right! "The current problem is that you set restaurants = [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] before the performFetch",you have really hit the point，thank you so much!@pbasdf

Comment: See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/nsfetchedresultscontroller.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH8-SW1) for the boilerplate code I mentioned.